# How can I create node in existing EKS cluster? or give me a solution for my error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl, amazon-eks

I'm facing this such error in kubernetes( *0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:* *}, that the pod didn't tolerate.)*. My application server is down.
First, I just add one file in daemon set , due to memory allocation (we are having one node), all pods are failed to allocate and shows pending state and fully clashes (stays in pending condition).If I delete all deployments and I run any new deployments also its showing **pending** condition .Now please help to get sort it out this issue. I also tried the taint commands, also it doesn't work.
As per my consent , can I create a node with existing cluster or revoke the instance? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure autoscaling (it doesn't work by default) for the cluster
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-managed-node-group.html
Or, you can manually change the desired size of the node group.
Also, make sure that your deployment has relevant resources request for your nodes